# How to get the space free in my Mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

I have a question in my mind that is it possible to get the space available and used in a MySql Database using PHP? I have the following MySql config --

```
SERVER: localhost
USER : root
PASSWORD : ********
```

So can anyone provide me a code or suggest me a code or can even give me link to get space available and used in a MySql Database of my Localhost server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [find the space occupied by records in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750853/find-the-space-occupied-by-records-in-mysql)

Comment: As for "space available", it's essentially the equivalent of the space remaining on the partition the database resides on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your space available in the mysql database table is based on your hard disk capacity, assuming you are not using a pre-allocated space innodb table.

To see the space taken up by a table just `cd` to the mysql data directory as defined in your config file. You will see a directory for each database. Then, inside those directories you will see the files for each table and can see the space taken up by each.